# Selecting index of array that has a value larger than a threshold

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of doubles and a threshold value.
I would like to select the first index in my array where the value at the index is larger than the threshold.

How the do I accomplish that in `LINQ`?

I got it to work with:

```
var n = acc_avg.Select((val, index) => new {Val = val, Index = index})
               .Where(l => l.Val > threshold)
               .First()
               .Index
```

But is there is better way?

Comment: How much simpler can you possibly want? You're already selecting a new array from your larger array, then appplying your where condition. Are you attempting to get an aggregate max value or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx):

```
var n = Array.FindIndex(acc_avg, x => x > threshold);
```

Comment: An explanation along with code is always preferred, even when it's something so simple as this.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks pretty decent to me, but I believe it will throw an exception if there are no elements in the sequence that meet your criteria. I'd consider FirstOrDefault instead of First and test for null before accessing.

```
var n = acc_avg.Select((val,index) => new {Val= val, Index = index}).Where(l=> l.Val > threshold).FirstOrDefault();    
if(n != null)
  DoSomething(n.Index);
```

Of course, if your object already had an index property (or if the location in the sequence isn't important to you) you could shorten this to:

```
var n = acc_avg.FirstOrDefault(l => l > threshold);
```

But you probably knew that. :)